# How to display the selected items of a treeview in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, treeview

I have no clue how to display the elements selected in my treeview. Ideas or tips ? please
The purpose of this treeview is to filter the data for export purposes.
The origin of the code comes from here (https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/#customization)

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import TreeView from '@mui/lab/TreeView';
import TreeItem from '@mui/lab/TreeItem';

function MinusSquare(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon fontSize="inherit" style={{ width: 25, height: 25 }} {...props}>
      {/* tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length */}
      <path d="M22.047 22.074v0 0-20.147 0h-20.12v0 20.147 0h20.12zM22.047 24h-20.12q-.803 0-1.365-.562t-.562-1.365v-20.147q0-.776.562-1.351t1.365-.575h20.147q.776 0 1.351.575t.575 1.351v20.147q0 .803-.575 1.365t-1.378.562v0zM17.873 11.023h-11.826q-.375 0-.669.281t-.294.682v0q0 .401.294 .682t.669.281h11.826q.375 0 .669-.281t.294-.682v0q0-.401-.294-.682t-.669-.281z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}

function PlusSquare(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon fontSize="inherit" style={{ width: 25, height: 25 }} {...props}>
      {/* tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length */}
      <path d="M22.047 22.074v0 0-20.147 0h-20.12v0 20.147 0h20.12zM22.047 24h-20.12q-.803 0-1.365-.562t-.562-1.365v-20.147q0-.776.562-1.351t1.365-.575h20.147q.776 0 1.351.575t.575 1.351v20.147q0 .803-.575 1.365t-1.378.562v0zM17.873 12.977h-4.923v4.896q0 .401-.281.682t-.682.281v0q-.375 0-.669-.281t-.294-.682v-4.896h-4.923q-.401 0-.682-.294t-.281-.669v0q0-.401.281-.682t.682-.281h4.923v-4.896q0-.401.294-.682t.669-.281v0q.401 0 .682.281t.281.682v4.896h4.923q.401 0 .682.281t.281.682v0q0 .375-.281.669t-.682.294z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}

function CloseSquare(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon
      className="close"
      fontSize="inherit"
      style={{ width: 25, height: 25 }}
      {...props}
    >
      {/* tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length */}
      <path d="M17.485 17.512q-.281.281-.682.281t-.696-.268l-4.12-4.147-4.12 4.147q-.294.268-.696.268t-.682-.281-.281-.682.294-.669l4.12-4.147-4.12-4.147q-.294-.268-.294-.669t.281-.682.682-.281.696 .268l4.12 4.147 4.12-4.147q.294-.268.696-.268t.682.281 .281.669-.294.682l-4.12 4.147 4.12 4.147q.294.268 .294.669t-.281.682zM22.047 22.074v0 0-20.147 0h-20.12v0 20.147 0h20.12zM22.047 24h-20.12q-.803 0-1.365-.562t-.562-1.365v-20.147q0-.776.562-1.351t1.365-.575h20.147q.776 0 1.351.575t.575 1.351v20.147q0 .803-.575 1.365t-1.378.562v0z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}

function TransitionComponent(props) {
  const style = useSpring({
    from: {
      opacity: 0,
      transform: 'translate3d(20px,0,0)',
    },
    to: {
      opacity: props.in ? 1 : 0,
      transform: `translate3d(${props.in ? 0 : 20}px,0,0)`,
    },
  });

  return (
    <animated.div style={style}>
      <Collapse {...props} />
    </animated.div>
  );
}

TransitionComponent.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Show the component; triggers the enter or exit states
   */
  in: PropTypes.bool,
};

const StyledTreeItem = styled((props) => (
  <TreeItem {...props} TransitionComponent={TransitionComponent} />
))(({ theme }) => ({
  [`& .${treeItemClasses.iconContainer}`]: {
    '& .close': {
      opacity: 0.3,
    },
  },
  [`& .${treeItemClasses.group}`]: {
    marginLeft: 15,
    paddingLeft: 18,
    borderLeft: `1px dashed ${alpha(theme.palette.text.primary, 0.4)}`,
  },
}));

const TreeViewBuilder = ({data, ChoiceDate, ChoiceModality}) => {
    return (
          <>
            {data.map((key, index) => {
              if (ChoiceModality.includes(data[index]['modality']) && (Date.parse(ChoiceDate[0]) <= Date.parse(data[index]['startDate']) && Date.parse(data[index]['startDate']) <= Date.parse(ChoiceDate[1]))) {
                return <StyledTreeItem  nodeId={data[index]['series'][0] + "_" + index} label={data[index]['series'][0]}>
                                <StyledTreeItem nodeId={data[index]['series'][0] + "_" + data[index]['modality']} label={data[index]['modality']}/>
                       </StyledTreeItem>
              }
            })
            }
          </>
    );
};

export default TreeViewBuilder;
```

Here you will find an example of the display I have.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can get selected node/nodes of treeview from the *onNodeSelect* event on TreeView element like this

```
<TreeView
   aria-label="customized"
   defaultExpanded={['1']}
   defaultCollapseIcon={<MinusSquare />}
   defaultExpandIcon={<PlusSquare />}
   defaultEndIcon={<CloseSquare />}
   sx={{ height: 264, flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 400, overflowY: 'auto' }}
   onNodeSelect={handleSelectedItems}
>
```

The callback event will recieve nodeId/nodeIds like this

```
const handleSelectedItems = (event, nodeId) => {
        console.log(nodeId);
}
```

If you are using `multiSelect` prop, nodeId will be an array containing the nodeIds of all selected nodes. If you are not using `multiSelect` it will be string with the selected node's nodeId.